# Loading image from a particular server in windows azure

Tags: image, azure

I have an image in a azure cloud server. When I load the page sometimes the image appear and sometimes a broken link appears. When I debug with firebug in firefox, `404 not found` error was thrown for the requested image.

The image url throws `404 not found` error because the request does not reach the server containing the image. Instead, it reaches some other server in the cloud and does not display the image.

How can I make the request to reach only the server containing the image in the cloud? Because this is the only way to make the image appear on the site regularly.

The reason is I'm using a handler which dynamically generates the url for the image in a server. If the url reaches other server in the cloud than the intended server, the result is broken image appears on the screen.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now I can render the image in windows azure without any problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for sticky sessions, which does not exist today in Azure.  You can implement it yourself using IIS's ARR, but ultimately this is not a good approach for a scalable, stateless, fault tolerant service.  A better approach would be to put the image in a common repository where all of the instances can reach it, such as blob storage.  Or even better, put the image in blob storage and serve it directly to the client from blob storage rather than through one of the role instances.

Comment: You should definitely use blob storage, not only for this reason, but because it's cheaper to store there than in a SQL table or mobile storage.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question because this site is not allowing me to ask new questions